# Odoo 14.0 product Image printing

Tags: image, printing, product, odoo-14

I need to print product image to the product label layout beside bar code. I have tried something like this in the report_simple_label template

```
<img t-att-src="product.image_1920" t-att-alt="product.name"/>
```

Only and empty square is printed. How can I resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have the source directory

```
<img t-att-src="path/to/your/product.image_1920" t-att-alt="product.name"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, if got the solution

```
<img t-if="product.image_1920" t-att-src="image_data_uri(product.image_1920) t-att-alt="product.name""/>
```